# Google api gettoken(Context,String,String) is now deprecated

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-signin

I used to use the `GoogleAuthUtil.gettoken(Context,String,String)` method to obtain the access token. Now that it's deprecated, I'd like an alternative. I figured that it now takes `Account` as a parameter type, but I really don't know how that works.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Account from email address:

```
Account account = new Account(email,  GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```